# How to customize swagger-ui?

Tags: swagger, webjars

I'm learning swagger, trying to make a little change and see if it can be reflected on index page. So the starting point is the index.html page, I made a copy of it from the jar file :

C:\swagger-ui\target\swagger-ui-2.1.0-M1\WEB-INF\lib\swagger-ui-2.1.8-M1.jar

and saved the new page as index2.html, added a line to the html content inside, and added it to the above jar file.

But I've noticed it has a .gz file for the original index.html file, don't know its purpose, so I also made a file called index2.html.gz and added it to the above jar file, then run the jetty server, and loaded the index.html :
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/webjars/swagger-ui/2.1.8-M1/index.html

It showed up alright, then I tried to load : index2.html, but it couldn't find the page, why ? Where should I include it so it will show up at : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/webjars/swagger-ui/2.1.8-M1/index2.html

The error message is :

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /swagger-ui/webjars/swagger-ui/2.1.8-M1/index2.html. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I got it done with the following steps :

[1] Create : C:\swagger-ui\petstore
[2] Copy swagger.json into it [ This is where you can customize ]
[3] Copy the index.html and save it as : Swagger_Test.html into C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp [ This is where you can customize ]
[4] Unpack swagger-ui-2.1.8-M1.jar into : C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp
[5] Create C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\css and move the *.css and  *.css.gz files mentioned in the original index.html file from C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp to C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\css
[6] Create C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\lib and move the *.js and *.js.gz files mentioned in the original index.html file from C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp to C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\lib
[7] Maybe move another few files in the original index.html file from C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp to C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\css or C:\swagger-ui\src\main\webapp\lib
[8] Comment out the following from the pom file

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8-M1</version>
</dependency>

[9] In the Swagger_Test.html file
    replace : url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";
       with : url = "/swagger-ui/petstore/swagger.json";

[10] Recompile and start the server
[11] Load page : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/Swagger_Test.html
            or : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/Swagger_Test.html?url=http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/petstore/swagger.json
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to change in the Swagger-UI? I have been messing around with branding/customizing Swagger myself. If you take a look at the swagger-ui.js file you will see that it is 30,000+ lines of code and poorly organized. They are also using handlebars and backbone.js which I am not familiar with. I added some custom features by simply manipulating the DOM once the page had been rendered. I did this by writing a JS file that was added to the index.html.